# Create a table with different number of columns per row where multicolumn doesn't seem to work

Tags: tables

I've created this table in Word to illustrate some data. I want to preface that this isn't an example, it's the exact table I'm using, but I cleared the data because it's not something I'm allowed to share.

[image]

I've read the questions I could find on this site regarding different columns size per row in tables, but I couldn't find something to make this work. The only option I think could work would be to create a table with many columns (I'm still thinking of how many columns I would need) and to do complicated multicolumns for each row that I have.

For now I took a screenshot of the table and put it as an image in my file, but that's something I would like to avoid. The last option I would have apart from that is to remove some datapoints from the table to make the number of columns fit but I can't believe this is the solution I'd have to resort to.

I've been asked to produce a minimal working example, so I picked the last three rows of my table because they illustrate very well my problem. I've created a table with 13 columns (three for the left headers, 10 for the following values). Since 4, 9 and 10 don't have a common multiplier, I don't see how I can achieve a result similar to the screenshot I posted above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{10}{|c|}{Section} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Some name}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{2} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{3} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{4} & 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{5} & & \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Some metric} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{--} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{--} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{--} & 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{--} & & \\
\hline

\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Some name}} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 & \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Some metric} & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & \\
\hline

\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Some name}} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 & 24\\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Some metric} & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which gives the following result : [image]

I was wondering, isn't there a way to simply specify the amount of columns that I want on a "per row" basis or something like that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). That is exactly what `\multicolumn` is for: _to specify the amount of columns_.  I suggest that you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem using dummy data so we know what it looks like.

Comment: @PeterGrill Okay I'll do this

Comment: @IEatBagels To have _exactly_ that layout you'd need to make a table with 120 columns (the LCM between the number of columns in each row) then use `\multicolumn` to group them...  Much easier would be to have several tables, each with a different number of columns, stacked on top of each other

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik How would I go about stacking these tables, that could be an acceptable solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a layout like that using `\multicolumn` you'd need to make the table with 90(!) columns (the LCM between the number of columns in each row of that table), then use `\multicolumn` appropriately to achieve that layout.

A much simpler solution is to stack tables on top of each other, each with a different number of columns, but all with the same width.  The document below does that;  the code could be made a lot more automagic, to make using it less painful, but that's left as an exercise :)

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{tbg}{HTML}{E6E6E6}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|*6{C|}} \hline
    \cellcolor{tbg}    & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\cellcolor{tbg} \textbf{Section 1}} \\ \hline
    \textbf{Some Name} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
    Some metric        &   &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}\par\nointerlineskip
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|*2{C|}}
    \textbf{Some Name} & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
    Some metric        &   &   \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}\par\nointerlineskip
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|*3{C|}}
    \textbf{Some Name} & 3 & 6 & 8 \\ \hline
    Some metric        &   &   &   \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}\par\nointerlineskip
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|*6{C|}}
    \textbf{Some Name} & 1 & 2 & 5 & 10 & 15 & 19 \\ \hline
    Some metric        &   &   &   &    &    &    \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}\par\nointerlineskip
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|*2{C|}}
    \textbf{Some Name} & 1 & 125 \\ \hline
    Some metric        &   &     \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}\par\nointerlineskip
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|*5{C|}}
    \cellcolor{tbg}    & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\cellcolor{tbg} \textbf{Section 2}} \\ \hline
    \textbf{Some Name} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
    Some metric        &   &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}\par\nointerlineskip
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|*4{C|}}
    \textbf{Some Name} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
    Some metric        &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}\par\nointerlineskip
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|*4{C|}}
    \textbf{Some Name} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
    Some metric        &   &   &   &   \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}\par\nointerlineskip
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|*9{C|}}
    \textbf{Some Name} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 \\ \hline
    Some metric        &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}\par\nointerlineskip
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3cm}|*{10}{C|}}
    \textbf{Some Name} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 & 24 \\ \hline
    Some metric        &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}\par\nointerlineskip
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is magic, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dirty way to accomplish this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ninecolors}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand{\ds}{\hfill\rule[-2mm]{0.5pt}{6mm}\hfill} %dummy column separator 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tblr}{
    hlines, vlines,
    width=\linewidth,
    colspec = {Q[l,m] X[c,m]},
    rows = {rowsep=0pt},
    columns={preto=\hfill, appto=\hfill},
    cell{even}{1}={font=\bfseries},
    hspan = even
    }
    \SetRow{gray9}& \rule[-2mm]{0pt}{6mm}Section 1\\
    Some name   & 1 \ds 2 \ds 3 \ds 4 \ds 5 \ds 6 \\
    Some metric & 1 \ds 2 \ds 3 \ds 4 \ds 5 \ds 6 \\
    Some name   &  2 \ds 3 \\
    Some matric & 2 \ds 3\\
    Some name   & 3 \ds 6 \ds 8\\
    Some matric & 3 \ds 6 \ds 8\\
    Some name   & 1 \ds 2 \ds 5 \ds 10 \ds 15 \ds 19\\
    Some matric & 1 \ds 2 \ds 5 \ds 10 \ds 15 \ds 19\\
    Some name   & 1 \ds 125\\
    Some metric & 1 \ds \hphantom{12}5\\
    \SetRow{gray9} & \rule[-2mm]{0pt}{6mm}Section 2\\
    Some name   & 1 \ds 2 \ds 3 \ds 4 \ds 5 \\
    Some metric & 1 \ds 2 \ds 3 \ds 4 \ds 5 \\
    Some name   & 1 \ds 2 \ds 3 \ds 4 \\
    Some metric & 1 \ds 2 \ds 3 \ds 4\\
    Some name   & 1 \ds 2 \ds 3 \ds 4 \\
    Some metric & 1 \ds 2 \ds 3 \ds 4\\
    Some name   & 1 \ds 2 \ds 3 \ds 4 \ds 5 \ds 8 \ds 12 \ds 16 \ds 20\\
    Some metric & 1 \ds 2 \ds 3 \ds 4 \ds 5 \ds 8 \ds 12 \ds 16 \ds 20\\
    Some name   & 1 \ds 2 \ds 3 \ds 4 \ds 5 \ds 8 \ds 12 \ds 16 \ds 20 \ds 24\\
    Some metric & 1 \ds 2 \ds 3 \ds 4 \ds 5 \ds 8 \ds 12 \ds 16 \ds 20 \ds \hphantom{2}4\\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Disclaimer: It has several problems like if the consecutive "Some name" and "Some metric" rows don't have equal width content in similar columns then the columns won't align. One way to correct this can be using the `\hphantom` command but it can be tedious quickly. Also, it would be better if the height of the horizontal rule were not absolute.